# Understanding the Great Orthogonality Theorem (group theory)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I want to build some intuition around the important Great Orthogonality theorem.

The Great Orthogonality theorem states that for a finite group $G$, we have (in a particular form of the theorem):
$$\frac{1}{N(G)}\sum_{g\in G}\left(D^\dagger(g)\right)_{ij} \left(D(g)\right)_{jk} =\delta_{ik}$$
where $N(G)$ is the number of elements of a finite group $G$ and $D$ is an irreducible representation of $G$. A word on notation: in the above, the subscripts denote the entries of a matrix. For example, for a matrix $A$, $A_{ij}$ is the element of $A$ at the $i$-th row and $j$-th column. Hence, the above relation could be written as $\frac{1}{N(G)}\sum_{g\in G}D^\dagger(g)D(g)=id_{D(g)}$, where $id_{D(g)}$ is the identity element in the representation $D$ of $G$.

In order to gain some intuition about this, I think as follows: since we know from the unitarity theorem that any representation of a finite group is equivalent to a unitary representation, using the unitary representation of the above representation, $D(g)$, the above statement is satisfied immediately. So, in this sense, the above form of the theorem gives a natural generalization of the case where we use a unitary representation to the case of using $\it{any}$ representation. Is my understanding correct and precise?

Moreover, in the above form of the theorem, it roughly seems like "averaging out" the action of the representation $D(g)$ (I am not talking about the unitary representation now) on whatever space it acts on and that "averaged" action leaves anything it acts on invariant (does not change it). I cannot really precisely understand this; I can only roughly understand it by saying that since $G$ is a group, $\exists\ g^{-1}\in G$ such that $g\cdot g^{-1}=id_G,\ \forall g\in G$ and knowing that $D(g^{-1})=D^{-1}(g)$ (where in the unitary representation $D^{-1}(g)=D^\dagger(g)$); using these facts I can get a rough idea of how the averaged action of the representation of the group does nothing, because for every action of the representation of $g$ there is also the "opposite" action of the rep of $g^{-1}$, something analogous to averaging out all the unit vectors in $R^n$, where for every unit vector we have a unit vector of opposite direction (although here we do no talk about the action of something on something). Is the intuitive picture presented in this paragraph sufficient or is there something missing?

Last, the theorem for different (inequivalent) representation states that $$\frac{1}{N(G)}\sum_{g\in G}\left(D^{\dagger}(g)\right)_{ij} \left(R(g)\right)_{jk} =0$$
with $D$ and $R$ being different and inequivalent irreducible reps of $G$. The way that I understand this is that the action of an irreducible rep is independent of the action of that of an inequivalent irreducible rep, in a certain sense. It is like the analog of an orthogonality relation between vectors. But, this breaks down because the above does not hold when we don't sum over the elements of $G$, so I don't really have a good idea on why it the above holds.

Comment: What is $D^+(g)$? What do the super- and subscripts mean? And do you mean the kronecker delta, which is usually given with a pair of elements as subscript rather than a subscript and a superscript? This question would probably be a lot easier to approach for people familiar with the theory if you looked through a book on group theory and adapted the notation from there.

Comment: (using $N(G)$ for the order of $G$ is non-standard and cumbersome, and denoting a representation by $D$ is unusual though not distracting. Using superscripts $(s)$ and $(r)$ to denote different irreps is definitely impractical given the abundance of other super- and subscripts, and one might as well just have called them $D$ and $E$ for example).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks for the suggestions Tobias. I have made multiple edits to the post now in order to (hopefully) make it easier to understand. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: The simplest explanation is that the representations form a vector space, in some sense. The irreducible representations form a basis for that vector space. The inner product imposed by summing over all group elements with the operation you describe turns the vector space into an inner product space with orthornoaml basis given by the irreducible representations.

Comment: And the tricky thing is proving that the irreducible representations form an orthonormal basis. I don't know that there is any satisfying intuition to be had about that – it's a difficult proof.